# How to extend Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

Tags: php, symfony

How to extend Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request and create my own Request correctly?
I tried to create my own request:
`class ChangeRequest extends Request`
But, when I used it as argument in controller action, I get an error
`Argument #1 ($request) must be of type App\Request\ChangeRequest, Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request given`

I want to create several requests extends Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, and use this requests in different controller actions. Every request contains JSON data and has its own validate rules. Now I use ArgumentValueResolverInterface for resolving this requests.

```
class RequestResolver implements ArgumentValueResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function supports(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): bool
    {
        $type = $argument->getType();

        return class_exists($type) && str_starts_with($type, 'App\Request');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument)
    {
        yield new ($argument->getType())($request);
    }
}
```

After that I edited services.yaml and the error disappeared:

```
App\Resolver\RequestResolver:
        tags:
            - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 50 }
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: Short answer is: you don't.  Pretty much by design.  Need to figure out a different way to do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. I need to validate different requests in my controller, so I wanted to create several requests with different validation rules)

Comment: We'd need more context on what the validation does for your purposes and maybe some examples. It sounds like you would want to use a [Kernel Event Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) such as the [`kernel.controller`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-controller-event) event instead. Extending and/or overriding the `Request` object could lead to some disasters results, given how Symfony handles the `Request` object in various other sections of the framework, such as the Kernel and Forms.

Comment: The `Request` class encapsulates the concept of any HTTP request. Unless you want to change things related to the protocol itself, extending it doesn’t make much sense. Instead, I think you want to inject something or modify something about individual requests, and I agree that the kernel events are what you are probably looking for.

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing when I am working on a HTTP API server project. As @ChrisHaas suggest, the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request class do not encourage others to extend it. Whether it is by its author design or not, this conflict with my concept on the PHP Object Inheritance that you can extends a class to add functionalities to suit your needs.

Comment: @kelvin, Symfony loves using interfaces and base classes and allowing developers to extend those beyond whatever the Symfony team has imagined. In this very specific case, however, I think they’ve decided that processing HTTP requests in accordance with the various RFCs should be more contained, and the benefits of controlling greatly outweigh allowing arbitrary implementations that can instead be done from `MyHttpRequest::fromRequest()` or similar methods. I’m not saying what you want to do is wrong, just that you’d have to convince Symfony that it is needed.